# How to prevent event listener from being registered twice in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a site. The site has two languages. English and arabic. It also has footer and the footer is turned into clickable tabs when it comes to smaller screens. The click functionality works as expected on one version of language. For example, it works good on english version. When i switch to arabic version, the site reloads and the tab onClick event seems to be triggered twice. It seems that the eventHandler is being registered twice when I switch the language.

How can I prevent eventListener from being registered twice?

Below is the code.

```
import { shape, string } from 'prop-types';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { useWindowSize } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/hooks/useWindowSize';
import { useStyle } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import CmsBlock from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/CmsBlock';

import defaultClasses from './footer.module.css';

const Footer = ({ classes }) => {
    const isMobile = useWindowSize().innerWidth < 1024;

    const initialized = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!initialized.current && isMobile) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                initialized.current = true;
                const buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll('.col-links');

                for (let i = 0; i < buttonElements.length; i++) {
                    if (isMobile) {
                        buttonElements[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                            console.log("clicked")  // gets printed twice on language switch
                            buttonElements[i].classList.toggle('active-tab');
                        });
                    }

                    if (initialized.current && !isMobile) {
                        buttonElements[i].classList.remove('active-tab');
                    }
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }, [isMobile]);

    const rootClasses = useStyle(classes, defaultClasses);

    return (
        <footer id="footer" className={rootClasses.root}>
            <div className="footerWrapper">
                <CmsBlock identifiers="footer" />
            </div>
        </footer>
    );
};

export default Footer;

Footer.propTypes = {
    classes: shape({
        root: string
    })
};
```

Comment: You can return a cleanup function as a result of the useEffect call. This could detach from the eventhandler :)  But why do you want to attach to events from react, can't you handle it in a different way, or is react just a small part of the application?

Comment: I tried that. It removes the event listener fully and then the click event is not triggered at all.

Comment: I'm not an expert in all these FE frameworks, but wasn't it one of the main ideas, to not write (get rid of) code which accesses and manipulates the DOM that directly, like shown with the OP's example? To me it looks like code-smell.

Comment: @PeterSeliger So, what improvement do u suggest? I am not an expert in this either and still trynna learn more and more everyday.